# How to check if an <li> element has a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-lists

can i Check with JS or JQuery whether an list contains a specific Value or not?

My Code:

HTML:

```
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="liste">
  </ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('Add').onclick = function() {
    var Nutzer = document.getElementById('Suche').value;
    var Liste = document.getElementById('liste');
    if (! $("li:has(Test)")) {
      var entry = document.createElement('li');
      entry.setAttribute( 'class', 'list-group-item' );
      entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Nutzer));
      Liste.appendChild(entry);
    }
}
</script>
```

I only found Solutions with li:contains but that is not what I want.

Comment: Firstly, using `!` with a jQuery object is incorrect. If you want to check if the element exists use the `length` property. Also, what is the value and where is it held? If it's in the content of the `li` then `:contains` is what you need. If it's an attribute change the selector. In any case we need more information to be able to help you

Comment: Why is `li:contains` not what you want? Does `textContent` provide what you want?

Comment: at the start is has no entry.

Comment: contains dont work for example: i may want to have an entry 'Test' and '2Test' contains is True for both

Comment: If you need an exact match on the word, use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) on the list of li elements

```js
console.log([...$("#liste li")].some(el => $(el).text() === "Test"));
console.log([...$("#liste li")].some(el => $(el).text() === "Anything Else"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="liste">
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfekt, that is what i needed. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped! Please close the question by marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: Yeah, as soon as i am allowed to.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with only vanilla JS actually...

Take a look:

```
HTML:
  <ul>
      <li>Banana</li>
      <li>Apple</li>
      <li>Test</li>
      <li>Cucumber</li>
      <li>Coconut</li>
  </ul>

JS:
  const li = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
  for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    // it is the same as contains
    if (/Test/g.test(li[i].textContent)) {
        console.log('I am the <li> you want', li[i])
    }
    // it is the same as equal to
    if (li[i].textContent === 'Test') {
        console.log('I am the <li> you want', li[i])
    }

  }
```

Cheers,

Comment: Also tried it but it gives me the same result as contains

Comment: Yeah, that is because of the regex, you can replace it by a comparison. I've edited the code, so you can check the difference between both `ifs`